# New Relic Server Monitor causing high WMI CPU usage

Tags: amazon-ec2, wmi, newrelic

I'm using New Relic Server Monitor to monitor our servers. Unfortunately, starting the New Relic service causes WMI to use 25% CPU. Stopping the New Relic service causes WMI to drop back down.

I've course, I've reinstalled the Server Monitor, but that didn't help.

I've tried to restart the WMI service. But, the system warns me that I'd be stopping four other services. These are Amazon servers, so things like EC2 console and Citrix client are running. I didn't restart WMI because I don't want to be locked out of my server or something.

Is there anything else to try? If I can't resolve this, I'll have to stop using New Relic, which would be bad because it's been so good for us.

Comment: Did you look at the newrelic logs? there might be a problem which causes the high cpu...

Comment: It took me a minute to figure out that New Relic logs to the Windows Event Log. I adjusted the Log Level to produce more events, but there was nothing that indicated any errors. While there, I also tried disabling SSL, thinking that may impact CPU. But, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We tried installing a number of hotfixes for WMI from Microsoft, but none of them resolved this issue.  This was only fixed for a number of our Windows 2008 R2 servers when we installed the Windows Server 3.2.6.0 version of the agent (https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/server-release-notes/windows-server-release-notes/windows-server-3260).  On some servers CPU usage dropped from an average of 20-40% for WmiPrvSe sessions down to a much more reasonable 1-3%.

Comment: Thanks. We don't use New Relic anymore, but I see the problem was supposed to be resolved in that update. I can't test it anymore, but I'll mark as "answered".

Comment: FYI we also stopped using New Relic (latest client) today because of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely caused by a bug in unpatched WMI. Microsoft has released a bunch of hotfixes for high CPU/memory usage of WmiPrvSe.exe. There are a bunch of hotfixes for each OS so rather than list them all here we recommend googling "WmiPrvSe.exe CPU usage Windows" here is a link with the appropriate hotfix collection or MSDN article. An example for Windows Server 2008 R2 can be found here: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1398.list-of-wmi-related-hotfixes-for-windows-7-and-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx

Comment: Indeed, it seems like there are a lot of people with WMI CPU problems. The funny thing is, the problem occurs on some of our servers, and not others. We're using Windows Server 2012 on all of our servers. I ran a search and there is only one hotfix relating to 2012.

Comment: We're currently having the same problem, also just with some hosts and not others. Have submitted this to New Relic as a bug but it could well be WMI related and nothing they can specifically fix. Our IT dept. is investigating the hotfixes to see if any of them address the problem, if so I will report back with a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Will. Please do, because this seems like a WMI issue, but one that is caused by the Server Monitor.